# xlwings: set foreground text color from Python

Tags: python, text, colors, xlwings

I'm using xlwings on a Mac and would like to set the foreground color of text in a cell from Python. I see that `range.color` will change background color which I could use but it has an additional problem that the cell borders are overwritten by the new BG color.

Is there any way to change foreground text color from Python and/or prevent the cell borders being overwritten by a new BG color?

Answer (score 2):

xlwings is currently still a bit light on stylistic features. However, as described [here](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/missing_features.html), you can work around like this on Mac by accessing the underlying appscript object directly:

```
some_rgb_vale = (22, 22, 200)
xw.Range('A1').xl_range.font_object.color.set(some_rgb_vale)
```

**Update**:
Nowadays, this is now natively supported by xlwings including Hex color notation:

```py
import xlwings as xw

book = xw.Book()
sheet = book.sheets[0]
sheet["A1"].value = "Some Text"
sheet["A1"].font.color = "#ff0000"
```

Comment: Thanks Felix.  The link no longer works.  This set the foreground colour of A1 to red:

Range("A1").xl_range.Font.ColorIndex = 3

More info on Excel colours:
http://access-excel.tips/excel-vba-color-code-list/, 
http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/font.html

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me

```
import xlwings as xw
import sys,os

FN = "test.xlsx"
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
fn = path + "/" + FN
wb = xw.Book (fn)
ws = wb.sheets["Tabelle1"]

# set background color
ws["B1"].value = "Field1"
ws["B1"].color = (255,255,204)

# set font to bold
ws["B2"].value = "Field2"
ws.range("B2").api.Font.Bold = True

# set font color to green
# color-index see here
ws["B3"].value = "Field3"
ws.range("B3").api.Font.ColorIndex = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

The new API is :

```
Range("A1").api.Font.ColorIndex = 3
```

Comment: can we set a color based on RGB values or is this approach limited to the "ColorIndex"?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is working fine for me.

`from xlwings.utils import rgb_to_int`
`import xlwings as xw`
`sht.range('A1').api.Font.Color = rgb_to_int((192, 192, 192))`